# Running 50 amps to detached garage

Tags: electrical, detached-structure

I am running a 50 amp circuit from my house to a detached garage that is approximately 150ft from house. What kind of wire should I run to the garage?

I looked online and it looks like it is 6 gauge? Should I use aluminum?

I will be burying the wire in conduit.

Comment: Is there already power fed to the garage?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease. It had really old wiring that was what they called nob and tube wiring.

Comment: You will need to abandon the existing feed, only one feed to a building is allowed.

Comment: @NoSparks under NEC 2020 you can have up to 6 feeds, but they must have disconnects right next to each other.

Comment: Is this for EV charging? Going "50A circuit" is a common novice error, caused by a "consensus" that is wrong.  It can bring many headaches and unexpected costs.    I suggest watching Technology Connections' excellent video on home charging.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica no it is to power my garage lights and table saw and stuff like that.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I thought where I said "feed to a building" it would be understood as wires between buildings, where NEC 225 says *"225.30 Number of Supplies
A building or other structure that is served by a branch circuit or feeder on the load side of a service disconnecting means shall be supplied by only one feeder or branch circuit..."* 225.31 and 225.33 allowed 6 grouped disconnects to disconnect all interior circuits, but that would be much more complicated than a 60 to 90A feeder should involve.

Answer (score 5):

Different types of insulation have different temperature ratings that effect ampacity, but your cheapest option is #2 direct burial Aluminum, your safest highest capacity is the same #2 Al in 1.25" conduit.

Options are:

UF cable is limited to 60°C rating, you wouldn't need conduit except $20 at each end where you rise above burial depth. Copper 6/3 UF at retail is about $4 foot. Moderate damage risk, moderate price, lowest effort.

More damage resistant would be THWN in conduit. 75°C rating is allowed, copper #8 is about $0.50/ft per strand plus $2/ft. for required conduit. So also $4/ft. More work, minimum risk, more effort (or talent).

Highest risk is direct burial #2 AWG Aluminum "Dyke Quadraplex" Mobile Home Feeder, 75°C rating is allowed, permitting 90A protection (if load calc allows). [It runs about #2/ft.](https://nassaunationalcable.com/products/2-2-2-4-dyke-quadruplex) and you just need the $20 of conduit on each end. You could also run this in $2/ft conduit bringing the price back up to $4/ft., but this may be your best option. Lowest potential cost (if run w/o conduit), highest damage risk (if run w/o conduit), highest capacity. Also you are only allowed a single feed to a building. The 90A capacity would also cover lighting and general purpose receptacles on the single feed, potentially replacing an existing inferior feed. If your load calc doesn't allow adding the full 90A capacity you can still use #2 and down size the breaker feeding the cable down to calculated size.

Also at 150 feet you may experience some voltage loss, requiring larger sized wire if UF or THWN is used, but lower resistance #2 Dyke Mobile Home Feeder (in conduit or not) will provide the best protection against this type of loss compared to other options, so  Dyke in conduit would provide the best protection and highest capacity at roughly the same cost as other options.

Details (AKA Disclaimers): Load calcs on your existing service may limit feeder size to less than desired. Disconnect, ground rods, and other code requirements will need to be satisfied. Local pricing and negotiating ability not taken into consideration.

Comment: Is this a good mobile home feeder wire to go inside the conduit? Link: https://a.co/d/2WJZjRc

Comment: Your vague "50A circuit" doesn't give enough information to determine if reducing the neutral would be acceptable, an inspector could require overcurrent protect based on size of neutral. Your better and cheaper option is 2-2-2-4 https://www.amazon.com/Aluminum-2-2-2-4-Direct-Quadruplex-Secondary/dp/B00A4HNL64/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3K55Z4RRS0T7G&keywords=nassau%2Belectrical%2Bsupply%2B2-2-2-4&qid=1704214304&s=electronics&sprefix=NASSAU%2BELECTRICAL%2BSUPPLY%2B%2Celectronics%2C180&sr=1-1-catcorr&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.18ed3cb5-28d5-4975-8bc7-93deae8f9840&th=1

Comment: The condition where a reduced size neutral is permitted (the "4" in 2-2-4-6) is when you have 240v loads that draw power from L1 and L2 and don't put significant current on the neutral. Where loads are just 120v lights and receptacles and it can be shown that an imbalanced selection of circuits in use could put nearly the same current on the neutral as on a hot conductor a reduced size neutral is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

To find out what size, you look at an [ampacity table](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/). For 50A, the options are:

- 6 AWG copper NM-B (but you can't use that outside) or UF-B (underground feeder cable)
- 8 AWG copper individual wires in conduit
- 6 AWG aluminum individual wires in conduit or certain types of cable

For long distances, aluminum is the way to go. A few key things to consider:

- You may want to upsize the cable or wires for future expansion. With aluminum the cost is often not that much.
- If you use individual wires then they need to be in conduit. There are a few types with varying depth requirements. If you use cable then it should be direct bury cable but it has to be deeper than conduit.
- You will need a disconnect at the garage. You will need a subpanel at the garage. If you use a "main" panel as a subpanel (just need to make sure it has a separate ground bar) then the "main breaker" can function as the disconnect. The panel can be much higher capacity than the feed wire/feed breaker - e.g., a 200A 30 space panel fed by a 50A breaker and 6 AWG wire is perfectly fine.
- You will need two ground rods at the garage connected to the subpanel.
- You must do a Load Calculation on your utility service/main panel to determine how much power you can provide to the subpanel. If it is too low then you need to increase your utility service ("heavy up") or do some other things to lower the total load.

Comment: I was looking at burying this wire in conduit but was not sure if it will work. Link: https://a.co/d/2WJZjRc

Comment: In theory. But a few things to watch out for: 1 - It says 100A, but it is actually only 90A when used as a subpanel feed. If used as an entire service feed - e.g., from a 100A meter main to a 100A (or larger, because that doesn't matter) panel - then it gets an 83% favorable derate and can is OK. 2 - I am not sure (I just don't know all the rules) about the neutral being only 4 AWG. 3 - You need to figure out the appropriate conduit size - it may require larger (from code and for practical reasons) than individual wires of the same size, because of the way cables work.

Comment: @AndrewMcdaniel yeah, that'll work for 90A as long as you can keep some semblance of load balance in your subpanel (generally not hard)